# Collecting and editing local data on a tablet?

Tags: android, mobile, ios, data-collection

I need to view, collect, and edit data that has to be stored locally on an iPad, though we may be able to get an Android tablet if that's the OS with a solution right now. This data cannot go through the cloud or be hosted on a server.

I've found options like CarryMap that allow you to view data on tablets but nothing that allows you to edit locally. Collector is the perfect app for what we need to do other than accessing local data. Saving it as a tile package would work in some instances but there are times we need more functionality.

Edit: we have data that cannot be stored in the cloud or hosted on a server. It needs to be copied directly to the tablet. Collector can only do that with a tile package basemap but we need more functionality than a static layer.

Comment: What kinds of solutions are you looking to implement?  Do you want to buy a license to build an application like ESRI's SDK for IOS or are you looking more open source?

Comment: ArcGIS collector https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.arcgis.collector&hl=en

Comment: You may wish to edit your post to include mention of what that 'more functionality' is and expand on why Collector won't work (assuming you've checked out the latest version).

Comment: Collector can be used in Offline mode and edits can be done locally.

Comment: QGIS Android (Tablet) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlQbsdR483k&t=11m40s

Comment: We have ESRI licenses but Collector requires the data to be in the cloud or hosted on a server. This data is too sensitive, it needs to be stored on the tablet. Collector won't work, QGIS is still buggy, but we're open to whatever works.